# Use special characters in jQuery plugin setting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, encode

I've run into a problem with a plugin I'm working on. I'm allowing users to pass some text to the plugin like so:

```
data-plugin='{ "setting" : "hello world" }'
```

no problems there, until a special character is introduced:

```
data-plugin='{ "setting" : "hello world, it's been awhile." }'
```

The apostrophe just halts everything and doesn't throw any errors. I'm not sure how I would go about allowing users to type this as they normally would?

EDIT: Here's the exact attribute that is causing the problem:

```
data-plugin='{
   "foreground":"1_foreground.png", 
   "horizon":"50,120",
   "subtitle":"Hello world. It's been awhile.",
   "subtitle_speed":"3500,2000",
   "subtitle_color":"#ff5b00",
   "subtitle_pos":"bottom"
}'
```

EDIT 2:

When \' is used in the setting, this is logged before merging objects inside the plugin:

```
{
       "foreground":"1_foreground.png", 
       "horizon":"50,120",
       "subtitle":"Hello world. \
```

Directly after that I'm using $.extend to merge this then apply it as data.

THIS IS HOW IT IS SETUP:

Call a plugin on a ton of elements:

```
$('.el').plugin({ "setting1" : "value" });
```

Modify those settings by using them here:

```
<div class="el"></div>
<div class="el" data-plugin='{ "setting1" : "special value" }'></div>
```

Anyways, that isn't the issue. The issue is trying to plug an apostrophe into the value. Single quotes on any HTML element is valid.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd need to know how the data is being saved and written for a complete answer, but this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1219983/1173601

Comment: I assume `data-plugin='{ "setting" : "hello world" }'` is an HTML attribute?

Comment: Yes it is an HTML attribute

Comment: You have to properly HTML encode all `'` before you generate the HTML. See http://jsfiddle.net/t9qv4/.

Comment: The html isn't being generated - but will be typed in by users for plugin settings.

Comment: Then how does `data-plugin` get its value? If it isn't generated, then the quotation mark should't be an issue. Please provide a complete example that reproduces the issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidance.

Comment: Or are you saying that if the users use `data-plugin='{ "setting" : "hello world, it's been awhile." }'` in their HTML, it doesn't work as expect? That's the user's problem, not yours. The user has to create valid HTML to begin with.

Comment: Just like plugin settings $('#el').plugin({ same thing here });

Comment: You said `data-plugin` is an **HTML attribute**. How does this relate to `$('#el').plugin({ same thing here });` now? As I said, you should provide a complete example. It's completely unclear for me now where exactly you have the issue.

Comment: Hey Felix, single quotes on an attribute is valid. It relates because you're passing Javascript plugin settings into both of them the exact same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data-plugin='{ "setting" : "hello world, it's been awhile." }'
```

Since you're wrapping your JSON string with apostrophes, you need to escape apostrophes inside of your string.

Change it to:

```
data-plugin='{ "setting" : "hello world, it\'s been awhile." }'
```

EDIT: Ok I think I have an idea what you're trying to do based on data-plugin being an html attribute:

I tried a JSFIDDLE to reproduce and here's what I get:

```
<input type='hidden' data-plugin='{
   "foreground":"1_foreground.png", 
   "horizon":"50,120",
   "subtitle":"Hello world. It\'s been awhile.",
   "subtitle_speed":"3500,2000",
   "subtitle_color":"#ff5b00",
   "subtitle_pos":"bottom"
}'>
```

and javascript

```
alert($('input').data('plugin'));
```

and it causes the error you noted in your question.

Per the first comment on your question, I escaped the apostrophe to `&apos;` and when I run

```
alert($('input').data('plugin'));
```

and I get a proper response. This will alert to a JSON object, so

```
alert($('input').data('plugin').foreground);
```

alerts "1_foreground.png". To turn it back into JSON if that's what you're trying to do you need to:

```
var jsonPluginSettings = JSON.stringify($('input').data('plugin'));
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tried, and oddly enough it doesn't work?

Comment: Once that apostrophe is escaped it's a sound string, such as: alert('te'st'); vs. alert('te\'st'); ... Just to confirm, you're getting NO console errors? If not, then I would need to see more code to diagnose what's going on within your plugin, and more of a description about what problem you're happing. Are you trying to create a JSON object, and it's undefined? What happens if you put an alert before and after the data-plugin line?

Comment: Hey Gary, just added to the question so you can see it in context. I was pretty sure escaping it as usual would do the trick, but no luck - and no console errors. I'll try alerting.

Comment: Can't type this on the main question yet because I don't have 50 rep, but I missed part of the original question, that users will be typing this in. I agree with James L. that we need more info on where the data's coming from and how it's getting into the JSON string you're using.

Comment: yeah, is this a "user" typing data into a form field or a "developer" adding a data attribute to an element?

Comment: it's a user - which is why it could be an issue. I've added the alerts and something interesting came up... I'm updating the question now.

Comment: Just noticed something, you're not escaping newlines on your data-plugin string. If you're going to run a string across multiple lines you need to. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: Line breaks are irrelevant in HTML.

Comment: Agreed, however based on his question, he's creating a Javascript string. To be honest, I'm not sure what he's trying to do so I'm grasping at straws. Don't think there's much more I can help with unless he adds more context per your comment in the question.

Comment: Correction, I see what he said reference an HTML element, not a javascript string. I will look at it from that perspective now.

Comment: Lol, I'll update this again - sorry guys I didn't think it was confusing.

Comment: I just found that I can actually escape the apostrophe using \u0027

Comment: just updated my answer with using `&apos;` as an escaped apostrophe .. Only thing that was confusing for me was whether this was a JS variable or an HTML element.. I was working under the idea it was javascript.

Comment: Awesome, now it's just a bit awkward for users to type &apos; inside their settings so I just have to figure out how to swap those out for real-life apostrophes :) Thanks Gary!!!!

Comment: Thanks for marking it as an answer! I can finally comment on questions lol. We can tackle the other problem if you wish, I still need to know where the users are typing this in, is it an input? or in another application? how is the data getting into the data-plugin attribute?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52245/discussion-between-gary-schreiner-and-aaron)

Comment: Also, the reason why `\'` doesn't work is because HTML doesn't have the concept of ``\`` as an escape character.